# Facebook login returns loginCancelled in Corona SDK

Tags: facebook, lua, coronasdk

```
facebook.login("6230773377xxxxx", fbListener, {"publish_actions"})
```

in the listener the event.phase is always loginCancelled and i don't know why. can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have something misconfigured.  If you're on Android, it's very likely the keyhash. But without more information about what device, your build.settings, Corona SDK version, it's going to be hard to answer.

You might want to study this tutorial/blog post closely and make sure you've followed it and see if that solves the problem.

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/30/understanding-facebook-authentication/

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest build, this was a problem that was found in the G2.0 engine and has since been resolve :)